# DataMapper to Dataweaver Migration

Tags: mule

I am currently doing migration from DataMapper to Dataweaver. I come across input arguments in datamapper. what is the best term to replace input arguments in dataweave?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using an input argument to inject some flow variable or use  mule expression language in dataweave. I dataweave, you can directly use the mule expression. For eg; (this is from mule documentation)

> Inbound Properties from a Mule Message
>
> You can take Inbound Properties from the Mule message that arrives to
>   the DataWeave transformer and use them in your transform body. To
>   refer to one of these, simply call it through the matching Mule
>   Expression Language (MEL) expression.
>
> In MEL, there are two supported syntaxes to call for an inbound
>   property:
>
> inboundProperties.name
>
> inboundProperties[’name’]

Here is the link: [Dataweave documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation)

If you have a particular usecase that you are trying to resolve, please let me know.